# Create excel file by fetching data from database and upload it to azure blob using Java

Tags: java, database, azure, file-management

How can we generate excel file from the table in the database and save it into azure blob instead of local system using Java and get the file path and size of the saved excel sheet in axure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your question in comment, you could ref this code example to upload a file:

```
//Creating a sample file
sourceFile = File.createTempFile("sampleFile", ".txt");
System.out.println("Creating a sample file at: " + sourceFile.toString());
Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sourceFile));
output.write("Hello Azure!");
output.close();

//Getting a blob reference
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(sourceFile.getName());

//Creating blob and uploading file to it
System.out.println("Uploading the sample file ");
blob.uploadFromFile(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

This example is using JAVA V8 SDK. I don't know which version did you use.

Ref the Azure tutorials:

1. [Quickstart: Manage blobs with Java v8 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java-legacy): In this quickstart, you learn to manage blobs by using Java. Blobs are objects that can hold large amounts of text or binary data, including images, documents, streaming media, and archive data. You'll upload, download, and list blobs. You'll also create, set permissions on, and delete containers.
2. [Quickstart: Manage blobs with Java v12 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell)

HTH.